# Challenging question about html form

Tags: php, javascript, html

This is the whole source code, i would like to modify it to add a new column to show the 
Client Mobile
Client Office Telephone
Client E-mail
in an another popup php pages.

What i have attempted is to add a form and a submit button to create a new column , when i press that submit button, the mobile, office,email information  will post to another php page to print out.  however, since there is a another form exist already, when i add a form ,the function in the following form will not work. (Don't worries , i will indicate where the problems happen.)

it is a complicated question. Thanks in advance

The source code is here:
https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B196kQ-9lu50OTI1NDZkMjktNzAzNi00MmM0LWIzMjgtNTQxMTIyZmYyM2I1&hl=en_US

the problem is at line 99

p.s. I just found out the form method can not get my job done, since it can not create  a popup window for the information at the same time.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for how to fix this.

Comment: I suggest using Stack Overflow's code formatting so that your code is a little-bit more readable. I doubt you're going to get too many replies with the way it looks right now.

Comment: Please format your code sections <pre><code> Ctrl+K

Comment: Please [format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) when you post it. Thank you.

Comment: go to edit and then select your code and click on the {} shown in the editor.

Comment: This became a challenging question to you . :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like at line 126 there is an extra `</form>` tag. Delete it...that might help.

EDIT:

Ok. So it needs to look something like this:

```
$_SESSION['echoable'] = $aVar; //put any variable you want here, such as POST data
```

Then, in the popup window, write:

EDIT: forgot to say, add this to the **TOP** of your page.

```
session_start();
```

Then do this stuff later on.

```
if((isset($_SESSION['echoable'])) && (!empty($_SESSION['echoable']))) {
echo $_SESSION['echoable'];
}

else {
echo "whatever"; // whatever you want here
}
```

The above will print whatever var you want. Hopefully this helps...if not let me know.

Comment: thanks for your answer
but it is for the form
<form action="changeStatus.php" name="stat" method="post"> 
at line 106

Comment: Yes. But go ahead and delete it...then could you update me on how it works? I'll be able to help you further.

Comment: Actually i would like to show the mobile, office,email information in a popup page for each job. That is not necessarily to add a form to implement it. I would appreciate in any way to implement it.

Comment: Thanks. phpkido. you are helpful. But I found that adding a form there can not create a popup window.

Comment: So you want to just create a popup window? Ok...lemme edit my answer

Comment: Would you mind put it on the google doc or some where and i could grab it for testing?

Comment: not just plainly popup box. i need to post some php variable to that popup box, and print out in that.Thanks~

Comment: I see. What about using a session?

Comment: you mind linking to the .php file on your server so I can check it out and see what's going on? (graphically)

Comment: how to do this? actually you can see the hostname login id and pw in my php file you can try.

Comment: i can handle the coding in popup window once there is a session store the value. 

I would be very very grateful if you can
1.add a button for each job to show details
2.Store the information to the session for each corresponding job that i can grab in popup window

given that the other function still operating without any error
Sorry for costing you the time.

Comment: I don't need the FTP stuff...all I will need is a link to the file. So I can access it via my browser.

Comment: foodil, if I can't see the page, I won't be able to help very much. There are dynamic things that I can't see. Like I said, a link would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I see. You can view the page :
http://www.sales.compbrother.com/index.php

UserName:James Wong
PW:combro

,The page is at Staff Jobs Progress, what i would like to do is appending the other one column called details in the right hand side of  status.Each with a button showing the details of each job

Comment: Do you have any unique ID's for each client? If not, add a "id" field to your database where each field has a unique id.

Comment: @foodil I can not work on this any more tonight. I will help you out tomorrow. I have everything set up and ready to go...just create unique id's in the database.

Comment: sorry phpkido 
i am using <a href> </a> for each popup link
but how can i  identify which popup windows corresponding to which jobid??? Since the session couldn't help, it can only store a whole list of jobid